# How does Python define Whitespace

Tags: python

Can someone provide a link to the sources where `whitespace` as used by default in the functions like `strip` and `split` is defined?

Do the functions `strip(chars)` and `split(sep)` use the same whitespaces when `chars` resp. `sep` are omitted or None? Please give link to source code.

Please note that I'm aware of this description on the documentation of `split:

> ASCII whitespace characters (space, tab, return, newline, formfeed, vertical tab)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR:** "whitespace" in these functions means all Unicode whitespace characters, not just ASCII whitespace.

---

The source code for the `str` class methods can be found in [`Objects/unicodeobject.c`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/91a8e002c21a5388c5152c5a4871b9a2d85f0fc1/Objects/unicodeobject.c) in the CPython source. Let's focus only on `str.strip` for now:

- The function [`unicode_strip_impl`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/91a8e002c21a5388c5152c5a4871b9a2d85f0fc1/Objects/unicodeobject.c#L11774) defines the `str.strip` method.
- That function delegates directly to [`do_argstrip`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/91a8e002c21a5388c5152c5a4871b9a2d85f0fc1/Objects/unicodeobject.c#L11756).
- That function checks if the "separator" argument is not `None`, and otherwise delegates to [`do_strip`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/91a8e002c21a5388c5152c5a4871b9a2d85f0fc1/Objects/unicodeobject.c#L11693).
- That function has two branches, depending on the internal representation of the string:

  - If the string is encoded in ASCII, the array [`_Py_ascii_whitespace`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/91a8e002c21a5388c5152c5a4871b9a2d85f0fc1/Objects/unicodeobject.c#L283) is used to check for whitespace characters:

    > Horizontal tab, line feed, vertical tab, form feed, carriage return (0x09 to 0x0D),
    >
    > File seperator, group separator, record separator, unit separator, space (0x1C to 0x20).

    Note that not all of those characters are included in the [`string.whitespace`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Lib/string.py#L24) constant defined in the Python standard library.
  - Otherwise, if the string is not internally represented as ASCII, the [`Py_UNICODE_ISSPACE`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/91a8e002c21a5388c5152c5a4871b9a2d85f0fc1/Include/cpython/unicodeobject.h#L896) function, which calls `_PyUnicode_IsWhitespace`, an API function whose code is automatically generated in [`Tools/unicode/makeunicodedata.py`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/91a8e002c21a5388c5152c5a4871b9a2d85f0fc1/Tools/unicode/makeunicodedata.py#L586).

    The data used to generate this function comes from the list `spaces`, which is populated [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/91a8e002c21a5388c5152c5a4871b9a2d85f0fc1/Tools/unicode/makeunicodedata.py#L442) with all Unicode characters which are either in the Unicode category `Zs` (meaning "space separator") or whose ["bidirectional class"](https://www.unicode.org/reports/tr44/#Bidi_Class_Values) is `WS`, `B` or `S` (meaning "white space", "paragraph separator" and "segment separator" respectively).

So the branch for Unicode-encoded strings definitely covers plenty of non-ASCII whitespace characters, such as U+00A0 (non-breaking space), U+2003 (em space) and U+2009 (thin space).

On the other hand, the branch for ASCII-encoded strings seems to just be an optimisation for strings which definitely don't contain any of the non-ASCII Unicode characters, and it should return the same result as if the other branch had been taken.

---

The `str.split` method is apparently likewise: it's implemented by the [`unicode_split_impl`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/91a8e002c21a5388c5152c5a4871b9a2d85f0fc1/Objects/unicodeobject.c#L12232) function which delegates to [`split`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/91a8e002c21a5388c5152c5a4871b9a2d85f0fc1/Objects/unicodeobject.c#L9681), which delegates to one of several functions depending on the internal encoding; the last one is [`ucs4lib_split_whitespace`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/91a8e002c21a5388c5152c5a4871b9a2d85f0fc1/Objects/stringlib/split.h#L50), the implementation of which is generated using [`STRINGLIB_ISSPACE`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/91a8e002c21a5388c5152c5a4871b9a2d85f0fc1/Objects/stringlib/ucs4lib.h) which is defined (for ucs4lib) as an alias for `Py_UNICODE_ISSPACE`.

Answer (score 1):

ASCII Whitespace Characters means the section of the [Unicode Whitespace Characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_character) that are in the ASCII section. This is defined by the unicode consortium, the [reference](https://www.unicode.org/versions/Unicode15.0.0/) can be found on their website.

Similarly, according to [the documentation of `strip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip), it defaults to whitespace characters, which, in this context, means what I have mentioned earlier. Same answer from [the documentation of `split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split).

EDIT:

Maybe I wasn't clear enough. The last two function, which are `str.strip` and `str.split`, only refer to "whitespaces" in their documentation, which means unicode whitespaces, as defined in the [`str.isspace`'s documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isspace).

Their bytes counterpart, `bytes.strip` and `bytes.split`, indicate ASCII whitespaces in their documentation.

Also note that the behavior of `str.split` is **not** the same if you don't provide `sep`, and if you feed it the default value of `sep`:

```py
>>> "a  b".split()
['a', 'b']
>>> "a  b".split(" ")
['a', '', 'b']
>>>
```